# PHP modify unknown number after certain symbol

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a calculator in PHP that allows calculating Square Root, but for this I would need to select an everything within the paragraphs that follows the symbol `√`, fx.

Input field: `3+√(6*2+1)`

I would want to get/select the different parts of this input, isolating `3+`, `√()` and the numbers inside the paragraph. So I would be able to first calculate the inside of the paragraph, then calculating the paragraph of that, and *then* get it back in the caculation, making it look like; `3+[calculated square root]`.

Is there a way of doing this in PHP? I've been told this is called "tokenizing", thought I haven't figured out how it works in PHP...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to implement is called a "parser". A parser parses an expression written in a language (here math) and separates it into terms or atoms. Writing a parser from scratch is possible, but quite an effort for non trivial languages. I'd suggest a different approach instead: take a look at so called "compiler-compilers" or "meta-parsers" like `bison` or yacc`. They bring along the actual implementation, you "just" have to add the precise description of the language you want to parse.

Comment: Have you actually tried Google or php.net ?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

Comment: @Jeff Yes I have, but it's a quite weird question to formulate on google when you don't really know what it is called - it was quite hard to know what to search for.

Comment: @arkascha Will check it out, be back :) Thanks for your replies